# Installing from Archive of Formal Proofs

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to install `Grothendieck_Schemes` from

https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Grothendieck_Schemes.html#

I downloaded the tar and uncompressed it. The contents are

```
$ ls -l
Comm_Ring.thy
Group_Extras.thy
ROOT
Scheme.thy
Set_Extras.thy
Topological_Space.thy
document/
    root.bib  
    root.tex
```

Then I run

```
$ isabelle components -u ./Downloads/Grothendieck_Schemes/
Added component "/home/username/Downloads/Grothendieck_Schemes"
```

but when I start Isabelle I get error

```
C:\Users\Aleksander\.isabelle\Isabelle2022\jedit\jars\isabelle_jedit_main.jar:
Cannot start: 
*** Bad imports session "Jacobson_Basic_Algebra" for "Grothendieck_Schemes" (line 3 of "/home/username/Downloads/Grothendieck_Schemes/ROOT")
```

So I suppose I should install the dependency "Jacobson_Basic_Algebra"? But there is no such package on AFP. I'm thinking that maybe I should have removed the ROOT file. It's contents are

```
chapter AFP

session "Grothendieck_Schemes" (AFP) = HOL +
  options [timeout = 600]
  sessions
    "Jacobson_Basic_Algebra"
  theories
    Scheme
  document_files
    "root.tex"
    "root.bib"
```

I tried running this instead but it fails

```
$ isabelle components -u ./Downloads/Grothendieck_Schemes/*.thy
*** Bad component directory: "/home/username/Downloads/Grothendieck_Schemes/Comm_Ring.thy"
```

How do I install these packages properly?

Comment: What is the version of the Isabelle release you are using?

Comment: @JavierDíaz 11.3 (Isabelle2022)

Comment: You should really install the entire AFP (as mentioned https://www.isa-afp.org/help/), not download the entries one-by-one. Otherwise, you have install https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Jacobson_Basic_Algebra.html too.